# Compile-time bitwise operations in C/C++

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm trying to understand how bitwise operations are handled by C/C++ compilers.
Specifically, I'm talking about C compiled with gcc, but I believe that the question is a bit more general than that.

Anyway, suppose I have a macros defined as follows:

```
  #define SOME_CONSTANT 0x111UL
  #define SOME_OFFSET   2
  #define SOME_MASK     7
  #define SOME_VALUE    ((SOME_CONSTANT) << (SOME_OFFSET)) & (SOME_MASK)

  static inline void foo() { printf("Value: %lu#n", SOME_VALUE); }
```

All the ingredients of SOME_VALUE are constants, and they are all known at compile time.

So my question is: **will gcc evaluate SOME_VALUE at compile time, or will it be done at runtime only?**
How do I check whether a gcc supports such optimization?

Comment: Look at the assembly language output (there are command line options that will do that in gcc - '-S'). The preprocessor should just substitute the text, so it's up to whether the compiler optimises what remains. It should.

Comment: This is known as "constant folding", and you can be confident that any modern compiler will do it at compile-time.

Comment: you probably want to read §6.6 ("Constant expressions") in ISO/IEC 9899:1999, which addresses this. Or alternatively [this overview](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression).

Comment: @Sneftel re. "modern compiler": [The Design of an Optimizing Compiler](http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3093&context=compsci) 1975

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, gcc will optimise this as it is a completely constant expression.

To check this look at the assembly code, for example with this tool https://gcc.godbolt.org/

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SOME_CONSTANT 0x111UL
#define SOME_OFFSET   2
#define SOME_MASK     7
#define SOME_VALUE    ((SOME_CONSTANT) << (SOME_OFFSET)) & (SOME_MASK)

void foo() { printf("Value: %lu#n", SOME_VALUE); }
```

I had to modify your code slightly as otherwise gcc optimises away the whole thing and leaves nothing!

```
.LC0:
    .string "Value: %lu#n"
foo():
    movl    $4, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    jmp printf
```

Answer (score 6):

Your compiler does not know about `SOME_VALUE`. The C code is first passed through the C Preprocessor to C compiler. You can see the output of the C Preprocessor by running gcc as:

`gcc -E code.c`

You'll see that the real code fed to C compiler is:

```
int main(void) {
 printf("Value: %lu#n", ((0x111UL) << (2)) & (7));
 return 0;
}
```

So the question becomes "Does C Compiler of GCC optimize `((0x111UL) << (2)) & (7)`", and the answer is yes (as indicated by other answerers who proved it by looking at the assembly code generated).

Comment: Thanks! I've already accepted another answer, but yours is equally helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

> will gcc evaluate SOME_VALUE at compile time

I don't know about yours, mine does

> How do I check whether a gcc supports such optimization?

I used -S flag to generate assembly code and checked it

```
    movl    $4, %esi
```

Comment: Check the answer from simurg. Your compiler does not optimize. It is the pre-processor. Also I do not think that op wanted to start a poll about the question.

Answer (score -3):

As others have answered, yes, it will. But do consider that is not *required* to; if you want the certainty of that, just pre-calculate it as you have all the elements to do it.

Comment: Any motivations for down-voting?

Comment: Compiler is not *required* to optimize, sure, but *why* would it choose not to, unless it's instructed to (`-O0`)? Taking into account that constant-folding is one of most basic optimizations available?

Comment: There are many cases where the compiler just can't optimize because of external factors (such as low-end hardware). And, of course, optimizations, simple or not, have to be implemented and, again, following the as-if rule, you **may** decide to apply some. If you wrote a compiler, would constant-folding be your first concern?

Comment: @black Yes, it would be. Constant folding is used so extensively in headers and standard libraries that *not* implementing it would be stupid. Not to mention, evaluating constant integer expressions at compile time is required to implement C properly; otherwise you couldn't determine array sizes.

Comment: @el.pescado IIRC, constant folding is enabled on GCC even at `-O0`.

Comment: You will not get very far optimising code if you do not take advantage of even very basic compiler optimisations. To be sure it is working examine the assembly dump and profile.